# encrypting a folder in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I am currently trying to encrypt a Folder in VB.net. To do this, I am using In IO.Directory.GetFiles to get each file from the folder, and encrypt each file using a loop. Each encrypted file will then be saved to a location, in its original name . I am currently struggling to understand how to have the output file save each file in their original name. My code so far is displayed below, any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Folder

Private Sub Select_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Select_btn.Click

    'Allows user to select folder
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        FileSelect_tb.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End If

    ' Gets files in folder
    Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(FileSelect_tb.Text)
    Dim directorylist As IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

    'Lists files in listbox
    For Each dra In directorylist
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Encrypt_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Encrypt_btn.Click

    'Password authentication
    Dim skey As String = InputBox("Enter a password of 8 characters:")

    'Check its 8 characters and repeat until its correct
    While skey.Length <> 8

        skey = InputBox("Password is not correct. Please try again:")

    End While



    For Each filePath In IO.Directory.GetFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)

        'Allows user to select file destination
        If FolderBrowserDialog2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Encrypted_tb.Text = 
        End If

        'Reads the file to create encryption
        Dim fsInput As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim fsEncrypted As New FileStream(Encrypted_tb.Text, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

        'Defines encryption method 
        Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider
        DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(skey)
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(skey)

        'Encrypts  File
        Dim desencrypt As ICryptoTransform
        desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor()


        Dim cryptostream As New CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, desencrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        Dim bytearrayinput(fsInput.Length) As Byte

        fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
        cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
        cryptostream.Close()
        fsInput.Close()
        fsEncrypted.Close()
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Encrypted_tb.Text = `? Is that some kind of puzzle? Why are you using the Dinosaur Encryption Standard?

Comment: save to temp file name such as `mydocument.doc` -> `mydocument.doc.encrypt`. if all goes well, delete .doc and rename the other.  BTW, windows will do this for you.